# getting the max value(s)

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Im trying to retrieve all the sightings that have occurred the furthest away from a set of XY co-ordinates, i was able to retrieve the first row in a previous query which gave the max distance. However it didn't have the capabilities to handle multiple max values if sightings occurred at the same co-ordinates.

Iv tried two different approaches at trying to get the max value(s):

```
WITH params as (
          SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
          FROM dual
         )
    SELECT sighting_id, sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2)
    ) 
    AS distance

    FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params

    WHERE sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) = 
     (select * from (select sighting_id, 
      sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) 

    FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params

    ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) desc )

    WHERE rownum <= 1);
```

And:

```
WITH params as (
              SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
              FROM dual
             )
        SELECT sighting_id, sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2)
        ) 
        AS distance

        FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params

        WHERE sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) = 
         (SELECT MAX(sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2))) 

        FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params);
```

the first way errors saying there too many values, and the second says i cant use the MAX() over the Euclidean Distance. How do i overcome this?

Comment: Your question is not clearly expressed and not easily understood. Please clarify what do you want do and also it would be great if you could add the schema/tables so that people may easily get your query. Think from the perspective of a person that does not know anything about the senario.

Comment: is this better?

Comment: where is `sightings` table's data? You should define it with some sample data within `WITH` statement before first `SELECT`. By the way, your second way works for me.

Comment: You posted 11 questions in the last two months and never accepted an answer. Does this mean that none of your questions has had a valid answer? If not, please consider accepting the answers; it's a way to mark the question as closed and to say "Thanks" to the people who tried to help you

Comment: Well said Aleksej !

Comment: sorry i dont actually know how. its not placed obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in first query you make two mistakes in where clause. You try to compare `SQRT(...) = select * ...`. `Select *...` return more then one value. Next you  try to `select sighting_id, 
      sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)` from nothing. You should point it. YOu may rewrite it to

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT sighting_id, 
       sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2))  AS distance
FROM sightings 
CROSS JOIN params
WHERE sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) = 
 (select max_value 
   from ( select sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2) as max_value  
         FROM sightings CROSS JOIN param
         order by sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2) desc)
  where rownum <=1)  
ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) desc ));
```

or

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT sighting_id, 
       sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2))  AS distance
FROM sightings 
CROSS JOIN params
WHERE sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) = 
 (select max(sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2))  
   FROM sightings CROSS JOIN param) 
ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2)) desc ));
```

or rewrite it with analytic function

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
select sighting_id, 
       distance
from (
SELECT sighting_id, 
       sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2))  AS distance
       , dense_rank() over (order by sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude,  2)) desc) as rnk
FROM sightings 
CROSS JOIN params)
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to take maximum distance. can you try with below one please and let me know if it works or not?

WITH params AS
     (SELECT -28 AS lat, 151 AS lon
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT sighting_id, distance
  FROM (SELECT sighting_id,
               SQRT (POWER (lat - latitude, 2) + POWER (lon - longitude, 2)
                    ) AS distance,
               MAX (SQRT (  POWER (lat - latitude, 2)
                          + POWER (lon - longitude, 2)
                         )
                   ) OVER (PARTITION BY sighting_id) AS max_distance
          FROM sightings CROSS JOIN params
               ) dat
 WHERE dat.distance = max_distance

Regards, Niraj